# When do native speakers favour Vことができる rather than the potential form?

Tags: verbs, potential-form

I have heard from some native speakers that for some verbs, it is more common to use the phrase Vことが出来る rather than the potential form in everyday speech. This arose after a discussion on verbs of the form *っする (for example: 接する、決する...) when I was told that the potential form (接せられる、決せられる...) is rarely used in everyday speech compared to say 決することが出来る.

Some sources such as https://cotohajime.net/2021/12/03/potential-verbs-vs-kotogadekiru/ claim that Vことが出来る is more formal, which goes against the above claim that it may favoured in informal speech for certain verbs.

If I could hazard a guess, I would say that speakers may favour Vことが出来る when using a verb they are not very familiar with as it is cognitively easier than conjugating the verb to the potential form.

Comment: FWIW I'd go with 愛せる, 略せる, 接せる, 決せる and so on in speech.

Comment: I would say 愛せる and 略せる, but for 接する and 決する I would resort to 〜することができる because I don’t know what their potential forms are.

Comment: Yes I just [looked into it](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B5%E8%A1%8C%E5%A4%89%E6%A0%BC%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8) and there seems to be a lot of irregularities in サ行変格活用 that I wasn't aware of. I understand why one would resort to the paraphrase 〜することができる in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I don't feel I do that when using a verb I'm not familiar. In some situations ことが出来る can be used as a light "euphemism". For example:

> 引き止めることができなくて、遭難させてしまった
> 引き止められなくて、遭難させてしまった

Both mean the same thing, but the former form adds an added degree of remorse. It also signals that the speaker tried hard. I guess it adds a sort of emphasis as it's more elaborate than the shorter form.